# Loosing half of my children after adding ScrollView (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add a ScrollView to the following xml_layout file.  But I am having a bit of trouble.

Ok so I have researched this and found that by changing  "LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" to ScrollView... I get the dreaded "ScrollView can host only one direct child".  So I wrap everything in a LinearLayout and my error goes away. The ScrollView works now, however I loose everything *after* my first TableLayout.  I do not understand why.

While "yes" I do want the answer I also want to know why this is happening.

I change the first LinearLayout and matching tag to Scrollview. Then add a LinearLayout right under the ScrollView and close it right above the closing ScrollView which is the last tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:stretchColumns="0" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:paddingTop="25dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_input"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Canton, Ohio" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cmd_submit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="OK" />
    </TableRow>
     <TableRow >
         <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Input like: &apos;City, State&apos; or ZIP" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:stretchColumns="0" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chk_usecelsius"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Use °C (not °F)"
             />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Current Tempature"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<com.kickintheapp.PapaStew.views.SingleWeatherInfoView
    android:id="@+id/weather_today"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="15px"
    android:paddingBottom="15px" />

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:stretchColumns="0" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="15px"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <com.kita.PapaStew.views.SingleWeatherInfoView
            android:id="@+id/weather_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        <com.kita.PapaStew.views.SingleWeatherInfoView
            android:id="@+id/weather_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        <com.kita.PapaStew.views.SingleWeatherInfoView
            android:id="@+id/weather_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        <com.kita.PapaStew.views.SingleWeatherInfoView
            android:id="@+id/weather_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: You gotta be more careful with those kids, man.

Comment: I've tried it quickly on my side and all works fine, I had to remove your custom views obviously, but that's the only change I made.

Comment: Well it seems that It didn't like the multiple tables with the custom views so.. I changed it to one big table(blah) and its working now.  You pointed me in the right direction.